# Print multiple row outputs as column values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sorting, printing

Suppose

```
A='First'
B='Random'
C='Degree'
D='Largest'

A='Second'
B='Odd'
C='Inclined'
D='Maximum'

print('Group  '+ A)
print('Number  '+ B)
print('Angle  '+ C)
print('Max value  ' + D)
```

My actual output is in this form,

```
Group  Second
Number  Odd
Angle  Inclined
Max Value  Maximum
```

Expected Output:
I want to arrange these indexes as column labels and store the output in a csv file as shown:

[image]

Like this if there are 'N' values, csv file should store all values 1 below the other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
A='First'
B='Random'
C='Degree'
D='Largest'

c = ['Group', 'Number','Angle','Max value']

df = pd.DataFrame([[A, B, C, D]], columns=c)
print (df)
   Group  Number   Angle Max value
0  First  Random  Degree   Largest
```

And then [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv('file', index=False)
```

Or use python only:

```
import csv
with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    wr.writerow(c)
    wr.writerow([A,B,C,D])
```

Comment: if I add second Set of A, B, C, D.. My Output CSV is showing only the 2nd set values. What can be done to show both the values for same data set ```df``` ?

Comment: My Second Set: ```A='Second' B='Odd' C='Inclination' D='Maximum' ```